# Ajax Get Method Not Retuning Valiue Using Ember Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js, handlebars.js

I trying to show drop down with ember js.Using Ajax **GET** method .but it could not returning any value.

**My Requirement only with Ajax**

Here's my code:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  model1: function () {
    var Category1 ;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:63951/Home/GetAllCountry',
      type: 'GET',
      datatype: 'application/json',
      async: false,
      success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        Category1 = data;
      }
    });
    return Category1;
  }.property(),

});
```

**Note**
Inside my controller alert showing fine.

alert Json are

**[{"CountryID":1,"CountryName":"United States"}]**

In my html page unable to get that value.

js code here

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
        {{outlet}}
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">

        <div>

            {{view  "select"  id="AddProfile_SelectCountry"  content=model1  prompt="Select Country"  optionValuePath="content.CountryName" optionLabelPath="content.CountryName" valueBinding=default }}

            </div>


    </script>

    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/ember-1.8.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/appnew.js"></script>
    <!-- to activate the test runner, add the "?test" query string parameter -->
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. I don't believe this is a duplicate as it seems the OP is having trouble with Ember, not JavaScript in general.

Comment: @blong You're right. Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: No worries @ArtjomB. , just wanted to update this for any other poor Ember sole wandering through here.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `Category1 = data;`, you are setting the variable label `Category1` to the value of the data. What you want to do is change the object referenced by that label.

Better would be to make `Category1` an Ember object, and set its properties by the data. Something like this:

```
        model1: function () {
        var Category1 = Ember.Object.create();
        $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:63951/Home/GetAllCountry',
                    type: 'GET',            
                    datatype: 'application/json',
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
alert(data)
                        Category1.setProperties(data); 
                   }
        });       
        return Category1;
            }.property(),
```

If your data is coming in as an array, but you just want the first element (like you showed above), you would instead do `Category1.setProperties(data[0]);`

Comment: Category1 return  <Ember.Object:ember261>

Comment: Yes, it will be an ember object, so the console won't print it quite as pretty. But it will have the data accessible like a normal JS object. I've updated my answer with a comment about dealing with the data if it's an array of one item, like your example shows.

Comment: hi carl. i have replaced category1.setProperties(data[0]); this line.but i got same result only Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed <Ember.Object:ember261>

Answer (score 0):

You could try that:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:63951/Home/GetAllCountry',
    type: 'GET',            
    datatype: 'application/json',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
            model1: data
        })
    }
});
```

And that:

```
{{ view Ember.Select
    id="AddProfile_SelectCountry"
    contentBinding="App.IndexController"
    prompt="Select Country"
    optionValuePath="model1.CountryName"
    optionLabelPath="model1.CountryName"
    valueBinding=default
}}
```

**EDIT:**

This one will work for sure but is not really performant:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:63951/Home/GetAllCountry',
    type: 'GET',            
    datatype: 'application/json',
    async: false,
    success: function (data1) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:63951/Home/GetAllCities',
            type: 'GET',            
            datatype: 'application/json',
            async: false,
            success: function (data2) {
                App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
                    model1: data1
                    model2: data2
                })
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Maybe you could try something like:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.create({});

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:63951/Home/GetAllCountry',
    type: 'GET',            
    datatype: 'application/json',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        App.IndexController.extend({
            model1: data
        })
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:63951/Home/GetAllCities',
    type: 'GET',            
    datatype: 'application/json',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        App.IndexController.extend({
            model2: data
        })
    }
});
```

but I'm not an expert in Ember sorry.

Comment: thanks..how can i call another ajax calling inside the controller

Comment: http://localhost:63951/Home/GetAllCountry url have Json .I have mentioned my question.That json not getting correct output.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're trying to tell me. Can you rephrase please? I invented `localhost:63951/Home/GetAllCities`. Replace it with the url of your second AJAX request.